# Haskell - counting the number of occurrences of a value in a list

Tags: haskell

So still working through Haskell tutorial...

One problem posed, is to write a function using:

```
count :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int
```

That can take a list of numbers & a value, and tell you how many times the value you specify occurs in the list.

It says to see if you can write it using List Comprehension, and again using Explicit Recursion...

AND, to use it to not just count occurrences of numbers -- but of letters, for instance, how many times does 's' occur in 'she sells sea shells'.

So I got:

```
countListComp :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int 
countListComp [] find = 0
countListComp ys find = length xs
    where xs = [xs | xs <- ys, xs == find]
```

and:

```
countRecursion :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int
countRecursion [] find = 0
countRecursion (x:xs) find 
    | find == x = 1 + (countRecursion xs find)
    | otherwise = countRecursion xs find
```

So it's counting the occurrences of numbers in a list just fine, like so:

```
ghci > countListComp [1,3,2,3,4,3] 3
3

ghci > countRecursion [6,9,7,9,8,9] 9
3
```

but when i look for a specific letter, it does this:

```
ghci > countListComp ["she sells sea shells"] "s"
0

ghci > countRecursion ["she sells sea shells"] "s"
0
```

it also said to try to count something else 'countable', like how many lists are there... so I tried:

```
ghci > countListComp [[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,5,6]] []
0
```

is there something wrong with my code, or am I not specifying what to look for correctly?  I'm thinking it's the latter... because the following works:

For example, looking for how many times 's' occurs in 'she sells sea shells'... do I *really* have to put each individual letter in quotes with a comma between??   Like:

```
ghci > countRecursion ['s','h','e',' ','s','e','l','l','s',' ','s','e','a',' ','s','h','e','l','l','s'] 's'
6
```

And do I have to look for a *specific* list?  Or is there a way to look for just a list with anything in it?

Comment: `"foo"` and `["foo"]` are completely different values. A double-quoted string of characters is just syntactic sugar for the list, i.e., `"foo"` and `['f', 'o', 'o']` are exactly the same thing. (At least, in standard Haskell; the `OverloadedStrings` extension, if you choose to use it, generalizes `"..."` from type `String` to type `IsString p => p`.)

Comment: A side exercise for you: suppose you leave off the base case of `countListComp` (that is, suppose you delete the line `countListComp [] find = 0`). What do you predict will go wrong? Does ghc agree with your prediction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem with `countListComp ["she sells sea shells"] "s"` is you have list of string.

You probably mean `countListComp "she sells sea shells" 's'`

Sting is just alias to list of character.

With `countListComp [[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,5,6]] []` is different problem. It doesn't count how many list you have. It count how many list equals to `[]` you have.

If you try `countListComp [[1,2,3],[],[4,5,6]] []` or `countListComp [[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,5,6]] [3,2,1]` you get `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Try seeing what the first item in `"she sells sea shells"` is:

```
ghci> head "she sells sea shells"
=> 's'
```

's' is a Char, while "s" is a single-item [Char].

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you have two mistakes here.

First, when you pass `["she sells sea shells"]` to your function you actually pas a list of list of chars to your function. So function call should be as the following.

```
countListComp "she sells sea shells" <second_parameter>
```

Second problem in the function call is, String is a list of chars, and list in Haskell consists of a head and tail list. So when you pass `"s"` as string, instead of char, you actually pass `['s',[]]`. So the right function call should be:

```
countListComp "she sells sea shells" 's'
```

Answer (score 0):

Same routine using filter and length.

```
count xs find = length (filter (== find) xs)
```

cheers